# How can I resolve this matter (c++ template with typedef)

Tags: c++, templates

```
//trep.h

#include <map>

template <class type>
typedef std::pair<Trep<type>, Trep<type>> TrepPair; //error!


template <class type>
class Trep {

    public:
    type key;
    int priority, size;
    Trep *left, right;

    Trep(type _key) :
        key(_key), priorty(rand()), size(1), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}


    TrepPair<type> splited(Trep &root, type key);
    Trep* insert(Trep &root, Trep &node);

};
```

a error is "std::pair : too few template arguments "
and it was arise diffrently whatever I precleard TrepClass.
Am I do something wrong?

help me plz!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using a `typedef` for `pair`, you don't have your `Trep` class defined. Hence the error : "`'Trep'` was not declared in this scope"

You can move your typedef inside the class specification:

```
template <class type>
class Trep {

    public:
    type key;
    int priority, size;
    Trep *left, right;

    Trep(type _key) :
        key(_key), priority(rand()), size(1), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}


    typedef std::pair<Trep<type>, Trep<type> > TrepPair; //error!

    TrepPair splited(Trep &root, type key);
    Trep* insert(Trep &root, Trep &node);

};
```

Also, the spelling of `priority` in the constructor member initializer list is wrong. It is misspelled as `priorty`

You also need to `#include <cstdlib>` for `rand()`

I am able to compile the code [here](http://ideone.com/EGFX87)

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as "template typedef" in C++.

Instead, C++11 introduced `template using`.

```
template <class type>
using TrepPair=std::pair<Trep<type>, Trep<type>>;
```

You'll also need a forward declaration for `Trep<type>` as well.

Comment: I put decleartion but cant run build because of this error.                                                                 " alias template type "std::pair<Trep<type>, Trep<type>>" is incompatible with the previous type of "std::pair<<error-type>, <error-type>>" in the redeclaration of alias template "TrepPair"   "
what is previous type?

Comment: Only you can answer your question, since only you has access to all the rest of the code.